# photoshop: gradient transitions

Tags: adobe-photoshop

how can I make a transition like this with photoshop ?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/transition.png/

I need to merge these 2 images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using masking (layer masks) to achieve the above effect? This [tutorial](http://www.photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/blend/blend.html) is not really what you want but it demonstrates how to use masks, or a [this tutorial](http://www.creativepro.com/article/photoshop-how-to-merge-two-images-a-custom-collage) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Blending Options?

Right click on the layer, select `Blending Options`, then Gradient Overlay. Try having a play about with that, might be what you're after...

Comment: yeah I've tried. I actually want to make an image to be completely visible on the left and to completely disappear on the right. thanks

Comment: You could use the Gradient Tool for that?